# Use Filename for Alt and Title Tags

Tags: php, images

I currently name all of my image files like this:

```
Earth the Blue Planet.jpg
```

Which when uploaded gets changed to this:

```
Earth-the-Blue-Planet.jpg
```

I was wondering if it is possible to have the image's alt and title tags render like this using the filename when adding them to posts:

```
alt="Earth the Blue Planet" title="Earth the Blue Planet"
```

I know the title tag shouldn't be used like that, but I'll just be using the filename as a base to add in the information I want. This would just make it easier.

Thank you so much! I love this place for all my Wordpress questions!

Comment: Did you modify anything yet? If I upload a file with spaces in its name, I also get `alt` tags with spaces...

Comment: Check my answer here it will help you get the same result you wish
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/359793/183606

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alt` tag already takes the filename but if for some reason you need to replace hyphens with spaces and include a duplicate title of the alt tag you can do something like:

```
function wpse_120228_seomadness($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) {

    $alttitle = str_replace('-', ' ', $alt);
    $img      = get_image_tag($id, $alttitle, $alttitle, $align, $size);
    $html     = '<a href="' . esc_attr($url) . '">' . $img . '</a>';

    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'wpse_120228_seomadness', 10, 9 );
```

This will only affect images inserted into the editor after the code is added and not images already on your site.

Comment: For some reason it's not working for me. I wonder if it's because I'm using other modifications. Here's what I'm currently using: http://pokebeach.com/filters.txt

Comment: yes the second filter your using is overriding it, it's also pretty bad.

Comment: Isn't the 2nd filter yours? XD

Comment: The second `image_send_to_editor` filter....